# Shortest Path with use of matrix algebra

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I have a directed graph $G = \{V, E\}$ with a source ($s \in V$) and a sink ($t \in V$) (let the other two vertices be $p$ and $q$) represented by an adjacency matrix e.g.:

$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0      & 2      & 9      & \infty \\
  \infty & 0      & 1      & 5 \\
  \infty & 2      & 0      & 4 \\
  \infty & \infty & \infty & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

I want the shortest path from $s$ to $t$, but I want to only use matrix algebra, ie. matrix multiplication and the like.

I already know that I can do all-pair shortest-path by substituting $\cdot$ with $+$ and $+$ with $min_k$ in standard matrix multiplication, that is:

$$
  c_{ij} = min_k\left( a_{ik} + b_{kj} \right) \forall (i, k), (k, j) \in E
$$

(normal matrix multiplication is $c_{ij} = \sum_k\left(a_{ik} \cdot b_{kj}\right)$)

Denoting this "multiplication" $*$ we can then do $A*A$. "Squaring" $A$ some $log(|V|)$ times will give us the shortest path from all vertices to all other vertices, in the above example we will get:

$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0      & 2      & 3      & 7 \\ 
    \infty & 0      & 1      & 5 \\
    \infty & 2      & 0      & 4 \\
    \infty & \infty & \infty & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

My question is now: Can I get the actual shortest path (that is $s \rightarrow p \rightarrow t$ or $s \rightarrow p \rightarrow q \rightarrow t$) from $s$ to $t$ out of the above matrix or by doing some other clever multiplication on the matrix?

Actually I'm not interested in the ordering of the route, but rather just which edges was used. That is, for the above matrix, I would be happy to get this matrix out in return:

$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

or

$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: It seems like the essential ingredient you'd need is an operator that extracts the $\text{argmin}$ from the $\min$ in your matrix multiplication, i.e. the $k$ value which produces the minimum.  It's unclear what you mean by "only use matrix algebra", so I'm not really sure what restrictions you are imposing.

Comment: Ah, I just mean that I want to do it (if at all possible) just by manipulating the matrix. I want to implement this, but can't have e.g. a triple nested for-loop. That's all I meant.